# hdfs dfsoutputstream cannot close, have always been waiting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using the the Hadoop API (1.2.1) to copy local files to HDFS, but it keeps failing.

Then I used JPDA to debug, and found that it paused when the code run at `org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(InputStream, OutputStream, int)`.

And very oddly, it had just paused when outputting the last block of data in the file, however the previous block of data outputted ok.

I thought that it might be caused by the file, so I created a new file with only a few characters, but the same problem occurred again.

Then I paused the thread, and found that the code stopped at below.

**My Stack is:**

```
> Daemon Thread [http-nio-80-exec-7] (Suspended)
> owns: DFSClient$DFSOutputStream  (id=288)    
> owns: NioChannel  (id=284)    
> waiting for: LinkedList<E>  (id=293)    
> LinkedList<E>(Object).wait() line: 503    
> DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.waitForAckedSeqno(long) line: 4002    
> DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.flushInternal() line: 3991    
> DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.closeInternal() line: 4097    
> DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.close() line: 4022    
> FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close() line: 61    
> FSDataOutputStream.close() line: 86    
> IOUtils.copyBytes(InputStream, OutputStream, int, boolean) line: 50    
> IOUtils.copyBytes(InputStream, OutputStream, Configuration, boolean) line: 100    
> FileUtil.copy(FileSystem, Path, FileSystem, Path, boolean, boolean, Configuration) line: 230    
> DistributedFileSystem(FileSystem).copyFromLocalFile(boolean, boolean, Path, Path) line: 1230    
> DistributedFileSystem(FileSystem).copyFromLocalFile(boolean, Path, Path) line: 1206    
> DistributedFileSystem(FileSystem).copyFromLocalFile(Path, Path) line: 1178    
> OperaHDFS.copyLocalFileToHDFS(String, String) line: 70    
> SearchController.urlRewrite(Model, LogObject) line: 596    
> NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]    
> NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 57    
> DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43    
> Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606    
> ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(InvocableHandlerMethod).invoke(Object...) line: 215    
> ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(InvocableHandlerMethod).invokeForRequest(NativeWebRequest, ModelAndViewContainer, Object...) line: 132    
> ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletWebRequest, ModelAndViewContainer, Object...) line: 104    
> RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HandlerMethod) line: 745    
> RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HandlerMethod) line: 686    
> RequestMappingHandlerAdapter(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter).handle(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Object) line: 80    
> DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 925    
> DispatcherServlet.doService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 856    
> DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).processRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 953    
> DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 844    
> DispatcherServlet(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 620    
>
```

and the pause code at `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.DFSOutputStream.waitForAckedSeqno(long)`

```
private void waitForAckedSeqno(long seqnumToWaitFor) throws IOException {
   synchronized (ackQueue) {
     while (!closed) {
       isClosed();
       if (lastAckedSeqno >= seqnumToWaitFor) {
         break;
       }
       try {
         **ackQueue.wait();**
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
     }
   }
   isClosed();
 }
```

My english is not that smart, but please help me!
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, and don't worry about your english ;-) I have tried to fix some of the grammar and spellings so that it is easier to understand. If you can please review to make sure it represents your problem accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked the reason of this problem, it turned out that the client at which the file located cannot be access to 50010 port of the DateNode as for the firewall.